# http proxy when using ConnectionRequest

Tags: codenameone

How can i specify http proxy details for ConnectionRequest? The reason is am having a Windows build which runs in a proxied environment and all the outgoing connections are failing due to the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing on the simulator, you can modify your proxy settings by clicking **Simulate -> Network -> Proxy Settings**.

For a Windows app, I'm afraid you might have to use a third party app like [ZenMate](https://zenmate.com) to control your proxy.

Comment: I think the Windows app would respect the system proxy settings in Windows, but I haven't tested that.